# Using SHGetSpecialFolderPath+SubFolder with SHFileOperation

Tags: c, winapi, directory, tchar

I want to delete the folder `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\appname` when the users uninstall the application `appname`.

First, I use the following code to get the path `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming`:

```
TCHAR dir[MAX_PATH];
dir[0] = '\0';
BOOL ok = SHGetSpecialFolderPath(NULL, dir, CSIDL_APPDATA, TRUE);
```

appname is defined as `_T("appname")`

The first question is: `How to append "appname" to "dir"?`

Suppose the above is done. Then I need to use `SHFileOperation` to delete the non-empty folder `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\appname`. So I need a double null-terminated string in a `SHFILEOPSTRUCT` structure. So

`How to get a double null-terminated string from the result of the first step? Just append _T("\0\0") to it?`

Update: I can use `TCHAR *dir2 = lstrcat(dir, appname);` to get the path. But when I tried to use `TCHAR *dir3 = lstrcat(dir2, _T("\0\0"));`, the folder is not deleted. Any number of `\0` won't work.

---

p.s:

If I do the following directly, I got it to work. The problem is that I want to it to be user-independent.

```
TCHAR path[] = _T("C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Roaming\\appname");
memcpy(path + sizeof(path) / sizeof(TCHAR) - 1, _T("\0\0\0"), 3);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For appending paths see [PathAppend](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773565%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

```
TCHAR dir[MAX_PATH] = {0};

BOOL ok = SHGetSpecialFolderPath(NULL, dir, CSIDL_APPDATA, TRUE);

PathAppend(dir, _T("appname"));
```

If you want ensure double null terminating of **dir** variable:

```
dir[MAX_PATH - 1] = 0;
dir[MAX_PATH - 2] = 0;
```

Comment: Should be `dir[MAX_PATH+1]` etc. for the additional null terminator.

Comment: @Xearinox: I am confused with a point? Suppose the real path is `C:\a`, but `dir` is defined as `dir[256]`. For the path to be double null terminating, we don't need `dir[4]` and `dir[5]` to be '0', but `dir[MAX_PATH - 1]` and `dir[MAX_PATH - 2]`?

Comment: But in code, all tchars of dir are initialized to zero, then dir[4] and dir[5] is zero, this is some of additional ensure of this. But in real world you must do some checks, such as buffer overflow, etc...